# Comparing the second element of two tuples with '<' fails in Python

Tags: python, lambda

I'm trying to write a merge-sort function that takes a list and a comparison function, in Python:

```
def sort(unsorted, comp_func=lambda x, y: x < y):

    length = len(unsorted)
    if length  <= 1: return unsorted

    halflen = length / 2
    lsorted= sort(unsorted[:halflen])
    rsorted = sort(unsorted[halflen:])
    combined = []

    while True: 
        if len(lsorted) > 0:
            if len(rsorted) > 0 and comp_func(rsorted[0], lsorted[0]):
                combined.append(rsorted[0])
                rsorted = rsorted[1:]
            else:
                combined.append(lsorted[0])
                lsorted = lsorted[1:]
        elif len(rsorted) > 0:
            combined.append(rsorted[0])
            rsorted = rsorted[1:]
        else:
            break

    return combined
```

It works fine with lists of *int* (with the default comp_func), as well as lists of tuples that have 2 *int* when the comparison function compares the first element of such a tuple.

```
comp_func = lambda x, y: x[0] < y[0]
```

But when I write the comparison function to compare by the second element of the tuple, the list returned is still the unsorted version.

```
comp_func = lambda x, y: x[1] < y[1]
```

However, if I change the '<' operator to '>' so that the list is to be sorted decrementally, it works:

```
comp_func = lambda x, y: x[1] > y[1]
```

Don't know why '<' fails on the second element of the tuples...

Having searched for a possible explanation, I found this: [Does python think 10 is less than 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187105/does-python-think-10-is-less-than-9). However, that is not the case; the list being sorted contain tuples of *int*, not *string*.

Comment: You forgot the test vector(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually show a transcript of how you changed the operator, so this is just a guess, but notice that these two lines

```
lsorted= sort(unsorted[:halflen])
rsorted = sort(unsorted[halflen:])
```

don't pass comp_func.  So if you did something like this:

```
>>> sort([(3,4),(1,2), (2,3)])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
>>> sort([(3,4),(1,2), (2,3)],lambda x,y: x[1] > y[1])
[(3, 4), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```

you would get inconsistent results because half the time it's sorting with a different comp_func.  Passing comp_func in the `lsorted=` and `rsorted=` lines fixes this:

```
>>> sort([(3,4),(1,2), (2,3)],lambda x,y: x[1] > y[1])
[(3, 4), (2, 3), (1, 2)]
```

Comment: I see. Just pass the `comp_func` to the two recursive calls, and it gives the expected result. Thanks alot!!!